# Preserving session ID's in django.test.client

Tags: python, django, session, testing

I'm storing django's session key (request.session.session_key) in a database column-- It's an app that doesn't require logins, and sessions are a acceptable enough proxy for a unique user. It works fine, *except* now that I'm writing tests.

Since the test client preserves cookies, I assumed it the session id would be stable over multiple requests. It seems like this is incorrect, though.

For example, I was hoping that in...

```
browser=Client()
browser.post(rating_url, {'term':'Helpful', 'action':'add'}, HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
browser.post(rating_url, {'term':'Helpful', 'action':'remove'}, HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
```

... the view would receive the same session key both times. It doesn't work that way, though.

If anyone can suggest a work-around, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: did you look at the django test client session documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.session

Comment: yep! the preservation of session keys is not addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the feature request for simplification of anonymous sessions usage in unit tests. In this ticket you can find the `hard` way to do it. Here is the link - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10899